# How to save data when vaadin binder has validation errors

Tags: spring, validation, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a vaadin web application with fom VERY complex forms (100+ input components). The data is bound to the form using a binder. The form has a lot of validation rules (required fields, validation number ranges, comparing dates,  ...). My Users sometime spend a whole lot of time in filling the form.

Is there a way to save the data from user input to database even if the validations fail? `binder.writeBeanIfValid(myBean)` does only write the changes when no validation errors exist. And `binder.writeBean(myBean)` throws an exception,  when there are validation errors.

I have added an additional button to manually trigger the validation, because my users want to check their input while working in the form. But sometimes, filling the form takes so long that they want to interrupt input, save data and continue working on it the other day. That is why I would like to allow saving even if validation errors exist.

Comment: Can't you make the form valid before writing the bean? e.g. remove invalid values and temporarily remove the required field flags

Answer (score 2):

"Save as draft" was not really supported in Binder directly in older versions. What you would probably want is `binder.writeBeanAsDraft (myBean,Boolean)`, which would write the bean with values passing the validators or everything passing conversion. First step of this was done in Vaadin 8.10 / Vaadin 14.1 and forced mode in Vaadin 8.11 and Vaadin 14.3.

Comment: Ok, thank you. When you say it does not exist yet, can you tell me if it is planned for a future release? For now I will try something like adding validators when my "validate" button is clicked, then doing the validation and removing the validators in the end. This should do the validation on button click and when user tries to save, there are no validators and therefore, saving will be possible.

Comment: I have made pull request of small API improvement which should make life a bit easier with requirements like this https://github.com/vaadin/framework/pull/11833

Comment: Oh, great. With which version is this going to be available?

Comment: @tigu it is going to be in Vaadin 8.10

Comment: I am using Vaadin 13, so I am a bit confused abount 8.10?!

Comment: It is coming there later, Vaadin 14.2 perhaps. Note Vaadin 13 does not get new updates as 14 branch is the LTS https://github.com/vaadin/flow/pull/7097